# I do not see how to set the required number of moves in the first time control in the "delay" options with DGT-NA

Tags: chess-clocks

In the "Increment" manual setup, it seems there is a way to set the required # moves for the first time control, when there is more than one time control.

I do not see the same functionality in the "delay" manual setup.  What if the tournament (note: the manual cites many different games, e.g., go, scrabble, draughts) has a different format, e.g., 30 moves in 60 minutes / d5 for the first time control?

Is it true that DGT assumes that the first time control is ALWAYS for 40 moves in the delay mode?

Answer (score 1):

I've had that clock for years. Except for mode 16 ("Up to 4 Time Controls with Bonus time per move, manual set with/without move counter", as described by the manual), there is no way to tie the move counter to the time controls; the way it works in other modes is that whenever a player reaches zero, the time for the next time control is added (to both players) and the flag falls. It is then up to the players to check whether the requisite number of moves took place, and decide whether to continue (the flag will disappear) or claim a win on time.

While it may seem like a missing feature, I would argue that the "letting the flag fall and have a human check the number of moves" approach fits better with the rules for tournament play, because the only authoritative source of move count is the scoresheets, or in some cases, a tournament director or their deputy witnessing the game  (for an exception see footnote below). For example the USCF rules say "move counters, on clocks equipped with them, may not be used as the only evidence in claiming that the prescribed number of moves were not completed in the allotted time". A good rule in my opinion because players don't always use the clock reliably.

My advice: ignore the clock's move counter altogether.

Footnote: there is one situation in which the move counter is actually authoritative according to the USCF rules. When there are less than 5 minutes left, a player who is planning to claim a draw under the 50-move rule can ask the TD, who "may insert a clock with a move counter that shows the remaining time of both players, set the move counter to zero, and order play to resume. When the clock indicates that both sides have completed 50 further moves, either player may claim a draw. If this method is used, the director should inform the players that if a move is erroneously not counted or double counted, the players should stop the clock and notify the director."

Comment: I have several different types of digital clocks, and none of them tie the move counter to the time control.  Which I have always found really annoying - I think, "I'm on move 45, the first time control is over - show me the amount of time I really have left, not the amount of time left from the first time control which has passed...."  But, reluctantly, I must concede that I (think I) understand why it's done that way, and that it's actually the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Probably worth starting by giving a [link to the online manual](http://www.digitalgametechnology.com/index.php/support1/manuals/clocks/dgt2010-na/179-dgt-north-american-manual-3-languages/file) for this clock.

It is worth at least browsing all the instructions not just reading the sections you think you are interested in because sometimes relevant information for a later section appears in an earlier section for which it is also relevant. It is then **NOT** repeated in later sections to which it also applies.

For instance, the answer to the last part of your question:

> Is it true that DGT assumes that the first time control is ALWAYS for 40 moves in the delay mode?

appears very early in the description of options 3 and 4:

> **2. One Time Control then Sudden Death (Options 3 and 4)**
>
> *Notice that the sudden death time is added for both players when one player has used all the time in the first time control* **(not after the completion of, e.g., 40 moves)**.

This statement of yours doesn't correspond to the manual:

> In the "Increment" manual setup, it seems there is a way to set the required # moves for the first time control, when there is more than one time controls.

You need to consult section **10. Parameters that need to be programmed for manual settings** starting at the bottom of page 8. There you will see what settings are and are not available in the different options.

In particular you will see that the only option which allows setting of the move counter to anything other than zero is option **16. Up to 4 Time Controls, with Bonus time per move ("Fischer")**. Setting of the move counter is *not* available for any option with 2 or 3 time periods.